# Should Ramadan-motivated questions be tagged "Ramadan" if they're not specifically related to Ramadan?

Tags: discussion, tag

There's many examples of questions tagged [ramadan](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ramadan) (171 Q's) which only relate to Ramadan insofar as that they're about fasting and the OP was motivated by Ramadan to fast and/or ask the question:

- [Does inhaling incense smoke break the fast?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/40924/does-inhaling-incense-smoke-break-the-fast)
- [Will it count as me purposely breaking my fast if I swallowed water while washing my mouth unknowlingly?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/40652/will-it-count-as-me-purposely-breaking-my-fast-if-i-swallowed-water-while-washin)
- [Is my fast validate if I do ghusl after eating sohor?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/40592/is-my-fast-validate-if-i-do-ghusl-after-eating-sohor)
- [Do you have to be obsessive in rinsing the mouth when you start fasting?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/40450/do-you-have-to-be-obsessive-in-rinsing-the-mouth-when-you-start-fasting)
- [Does taking birth control break my fast?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/40215/does-taking-birth-control-break-my-fast)

These questions are not asking about Ramadan, they're asking about fasting.  They could equally apply to voluntary fasts or catch-up fasts outside of Ramadan.

**Question**: Should Ramadan-motivated questions be tagged "Ramadan" if they're not specifically related to Ramadan?

It would take a while to go through these.

Answer (score 1):

I think if people want to ask about a ruling related to Ramadan they are invited to tag it, else fasting is not restricted on this month, so most of these questions my apply generally, we still have the possibility to help people focus or "correct" their question draft by commenting whether the question is specific for Ramadan or not.

If the question content seems to indicate that the question is restricted to Ramadan of course we can tag them "correctly"!